# Javascript code inefficiency

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

So im making a website and the buttons that are on the side i want to overlap on each other as they scroll. i managed to get this to work but my javascript code is very long and i cant figure out how else i would go about doing it does anyone else have any way of doing it and can you provide an example here it is and ill provide a link to a jsfiddle if you want to see how it works [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CaALc/1/)

```
    function overlap(){
    var b1 = document.getElementById("b1");  //gets all the button elements by id
    var b2 = document.getElementById("b2");
    var b3 = document.getElementById("b3");
    var b4 = document.getElementById("b4");
    var b5 = document.getElementById("b5");
    var b6 = document.getElementById("b6");
    var b7 = document.getElementById("b7");
    var b8 = document.getElementById("b8");
    var curY = window.pageYOffset            // gets the current scroll offset in pixels and stores it in curY

    if(curY > 160){                          //if scroll is more than 160 b2 becomes fixed at 20px off the top
        b2.style.position = "fixed"
        b2.style.top = "20px"
    }
    if(curY > 320){                          //if scroll is more than 320 b3 becomes fixed at 20px off the top
        b3.style.position = "fixed"
        b3.style.top = "20px"
    }
    if(curY > 480){                          //if scroll is more than 480 b3 becomes fixed at 20px off the top
        b4.style.position = "fixed"          //and so on until 1120 off the top to stack all the buttons on top of each other
        b4.style.top = "20px"
    }
    if(curY > 640){
        b5.style.position = "fixed"
        b5.style.top = "20px"
    }
    if(curY > 800){
        b6.style.position = "fixed"
        b6.style.top = "20px"
    }
    if(curY > 960){
        b7.style.position = "fixed"
        b7.style.top = "20px"
    }
    if(curY > 1120){
        b8.style.position = "fixed"
        b8.style.top = "20px"
    }



    if(curY < 160){                      //if scroll becomes less than 160 b2 becomes absolute at its original px of the top
        b2.style.position = "absolute"   //and so on until the original position of b8 is reset
        b2.style.top = "180px"
    }
    if(curY < 320){
        b3.style.position = "absolute"
        b3.style.top = "340px"
    }
    if(curY < 480){
        b4.style.position = "absolute"
        b4.style.top = "500px"
    }
    if(curY < 640){
        b5.style.position = "absolute"
        b5.style.top = "660px"
    }
    if(curY < 800){
        b6.style.position = "absolute"
        b6.style.top = "820px"
    }
    if(curY < 960){
        b7.style.position = "absolute"
        b7.style.top = "980px"
    }
    if(curY < 1120){
        b8.style.position = "absolute"
        b8.style.top = "1140px"
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll",overlap,false); //calls the function repeatedly as soon a the scroll changes
```

all those if statements should be replaced by something but i cant figure out what ?
thanks in advance

Comment: This question seems like a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about throwing it all in a for loop and using the index to map to what you want. Something like this should do the trick.

```
function overlap() {
    var curY = window.pageYOffset,
        offset = 160;
    for (var i = 1, i <= 8; i++) {
        var elem = document.getElementById("b" + i);
        if (curY > offset * i) {
            elem.style.position = "fixed";
            elem.style.top = "20px";
        } else {
            elem.style.position = "absolute";
            elem.style.top = offset * i + 20 + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want it to be a little faster, don't get the elements every time. Maybe something like this?

```
var overlap = (function() {
    var elements = [
        document.getElementById("b1"),
        document.getElementById("b2"),
        document.getElementById("b3"),
        document.getElementById("b4"),
        document.getElementById("b5"),
        document.getElementById("b6"),
        document.getElementById("b7"),
        document.getElementById("b8")
    ];
    return function() {
        var offset = 160;
        for (var i = 1, i <= elements.length; i++) {
            var elem = elements[i-1];
            if (curY > offset * i) {
                elem.style.position = "fixed";
                elem.style.top = "20px";
            } else {
                elem.style.position = "absolute";
                elem.style.top = offset * i + 20 + "px";
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: im testing this but the thing is that the element b1 never gets modified but in your loop it starts at 1 so after i changed it to 2 the code if (curY > offset * i)  is no longer correct as 2 is ment to be 160 but now i get 320 as offset is 160 and then * 2

Comment: ok so i got it by leaving the rest of your code as it was i took 1 from if the if statement like so if(curY > offset * (i - 1)) and then in the else statement took 1 from i too then i also made the loop start at 2 and everything works perfectly. Thanks !